# Notifications when a user blocks your facebook app/plugin?

Tags: facebook

If a user allows access to a facebook plugin for website foo.com, is it possible for foo.com to be notified when the user no longer allows them the same access they originally had?

We have a case where users are granted additional privileges when they link to facebook and prefer to be notified when they revoke those privileges rather than, for example, doing a check when they login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check has a user installed your app (and/or has not uninstalled it) it's fairly simple, make a `GET` call to /{user id}/?fields=installed using your [app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin). It should return installed: 1 for users that have your app installed.

This is a replacement for the old [users.isAppuser](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.isAppUser/) API call

Comment: Cool, that's what I thought, thanks. I want to build an architecture that could scale to 10M users potentially, so this it's not possible to poll for events. We're going with a "check upon user login" approach instead. But getting notifications would be ideal.